# onDestroy() not getting called while the activity is getting killed by the user?

Tags: android, callback, notifications, ondestroy

I have an activity with two tabs. Clicking on two tabs will change the the fragments below the tabs. While that activity is in front I give out a notification, After that I minimize the app and kill  that activity(not force stopping).

My problem is that am not getting call back in `onDestroy` while the activity is been killed by the user. Now if I click the notification the app will force close and thats because the activity for pending intent is been missing. Why am not getting the call back in onDestroy?

Comment: @Hardik I assume that your expectation is that people will post questions, then not read the answers?

Comment: @Simon what you want to say my answer is wrong for this question!!!?

Comment: @Simon you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not sure to get callback in fragment's `onDestroy()`. When we kill the app Activity's `onDestroy()` will get the callback and the activity will be killed and fragment may not get callback.

Answer (score 7):

I found solution of that:

1. Create service:

   ```
   public class MyService extends Service {

       @Override
       public final int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
           return START_STICKY;
       }

       @Override
       public final IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "APP KILLED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // here your app is killed by user

           try {
               stopService(new Intent(this, this.getClass()));
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
               super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
           } else{}
       }
   }
   ```

and then start your service when app start:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

make sure you register service in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name="yourPackageName.MyService"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Comment: Oh my god wow what a fantastic work man..
just wanted to tell you use proper package instaed of this     android:name=".services.MyService"

Comment: This solution works pretty well for me. It is also recommended by the Google development team, see the comments from Dianne Hackborn: https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/GfwRYCC42uX.

I would recommend calling startService() only from that activity, for which it is important to react on when it gets killed.

Answer (score 3):

`onDestroy` is guaranteed to be called when you explicitly call `finish()`.

On the contrary, when you are minimizing your app by pressing Home key `onDestroy` may well not be called right now. If your app stays in the background for a long time then `onDestroy` will be called.

For debugging purposes you can enable `Settings|Developer Options|Don't save Activities`. This way `onDestroy` will be called immediately when your app goes to background.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. Exactly the second point. I minimizes the app and kills the app via swiping the app from the list of active applications. In all other apps am getting the call back in onDestroy but am not getting in this one. Whhy like that? Activity is singleTop.

Comment: may be because you have to force stop? from the application settings?

Comment: If you forcibly kill your app onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called. The only scenario in which onDestroy is guaranteed to be called is when you call finish() from your app.

Comment: Ohh that wat the problem is, any possible way to detect while the application is being killed by the user.???

Comment: Maybe, as others have suggested onStop() would be as good for your purposes? onStop() is guaranteed to be called whenever your Activity screen *becomes fully invisible*

Comment: when moving from activity A to B, the onDestroy() of A is called! This i see in a LG phone that runs JB 4.1.2 whereas I didn't see this in my nexus 7 running KitKat. Is there any explanation for android to breach its own activity life cycle?

Comment: Where do you see the breach? According to the lifecycle it is possible for onDestroy() to be called after onStop(). Moreover, you can force this behaviour for debugging purposes in Developer Options|Don't keep Activities

Comment: `If your app stays in the background for a long time then onDestroy will be called` Any references?

Answer (score 0):

As stated jn the documentation, onDestroy() can't be depended on, it will be called when the OS wants to kill the app, say in low memory conditions. Thus when the user hits the back button or home, onPause() or onStop() are called in place of it. Try implementing your callback in thr onPause() or onStop() method.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I had already donre that. Thats not my requirement. I need to get the call back when the used swipes and kills the app. Am gettgin call back on onPause and onStop but not in onDestroy. thats wre am stuck.

Comment: Swiping an app from recent apps will only kill most apps, some still run in the background.