# Start service after app is killed or being killed

Tags: android, android-activity, service

It's gotta be really silly question but i couldn't understand why activity **onDestroy()** method hasn't been called after killing app from recent tasks. I want to start service once app is being killed. Now i am not sure whether i could start service or not as **onDestory()** method never been called :-( ;

I killed the app from recent tasks. Here is how i start service

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}
```

Manifest declaration

```
<service
       android:name="com.example.activities.MyService"
       android:exported="true"
       android:process=":CustomService"/>
```

**Update**

it is said [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) that Activity's **onDestroy** method is not guarantee to be called every time and code shouldn't rely on this function. So ended up looking for other way round to meet my requirements

Comment: There is no promise that onDestroy will ever be called.  Apps should not rely on it.

Comment: Hmmm never knew that it would be an consideration . then how shd i start service after app is being killed ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want call a `Service` when app closed , you can use **OnStop();** method too.

Answer (score 0):

Try the second solution in the following link and let me know the result.

[onDestroy() not getting called while the activity is getting killed by the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943636/ondestroy-not-getting-called-while-the-activity-is-getting-killed-by-the-user)

Answer (score -1):

I have not in your case but try to put startService before super.onDestroy